# Display property not working properly in IE for styling font awesome icons

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

[This is in IE 11 with css properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTuTq.png)

[After disabling display property, the result looks like below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGUIe.png)

In first screenshot, icon is there but not it's not visible.

I don't want to remove display:table-cell property. I need this for responsiveness. Can somebody please provide me a better solution.

Comment: without your code or any example how can we help?

Answer (score 0):

Don't change FA icons core css, they are best suited to be used as text, so all text manipulation properties will work just fine, everything else should be left as is. If you need to change some display, wrap icon with another element and apply css for it.

Comment: I have used FA properties like font-family, content, etc in other elements. It working fine. But this is not appearing. I thought it is because of display property

Comment: @SharjilKhan Yes, it may be caused by display property. `fa` elements has special css that is required for them to work and look good.